# How to merge two BLOB values and extract documents in .C#

Tags: c#, merge, blob

My files are spread across multiple rows in BLOB cloumns.I  need to extract documents by combing all the BLOB values of a particular file from two diffirent two columns (value stored in columns as BLOB)

Comment: Fantastic. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It might help to read [tour] and [ask] then to edit your question with more information so that we can help you.